# delete unwanted properties from the javascript object

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a javascript object like the one below with several fields and arrays and arrays within arrays. I'm only interested only in non-junk fields and wanted to remove all the junk properties from the objects. How can I do that using [lodash](https://lodash.com)?

I can do that by using `delete`, but I don't want to do that because that list is huge and I don't want to keep changing my code to write a delete every time a new junk property is added to my object.

```
{
 state: 'New York',
 country: 'usa',
 counties : [['washington','DC'],'Long Island',['New','Jersey']], 
 city : 'Manhattan',
 zip: '43543545',
 JunkOne : ['3453454','45345','45345'],
 JunkTwo: '5454545',
 JunkThree: {adc:'4545',vdfd:'45345'} 
}
```

Comment: use either delete operator to delete specific properties or use object.assign to select specific properties

Comment: use a whitelist instead of a black list; loop props, check key, delete if needed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `lodash.pick()` to create an object with only the requested keys.  For example:

```
var city = {
  state: 'New York',
  country: 'usa',
  counties : [['washington','DC'],'Long Island',['New','Jersey']], 
  city : 'Manhattan',
  zip: '43543545',
  JunkOne : ['3453454','45345','45345'],
  JunkTwo: '5454545',
  JunkThree: {adc:'4545',vdfd:'45345'}
}
var lodash = require('lodash');
city = lodash.pick(city, ['state', 'country', 'counties','city','zip']);
```

City now should have all the useful data, and none of the junk.

Answer (score 18):

use either delete operator to delete specific properties

```
delete data.JunkOne;
```

or use object.assign to select specific properties

```
var a = Object.assign({}, { counties: data.counties});
```

EDIT:

Doing it lodash way would be

```
var a = _.omit(data, ['JunkOne']);
```

or

```
var a = _.pick(data, ['counties']);
```

Comment: If using Lodash, note that **omit** is considerably slower than **pick**. Docs: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#omit

Comment: Well, I haven't done a bench-marking precisely but it totally depends on two factors : 1. How many attributes you have to delete or preserve. 2. How close lodash's implementation is to vanilla javascript. You might be right in all the cases or maybe just in some cases if it comes down to first point. I am not sure though...

Comment: More importantly, as of version 5.0, [lodash is dropping _.omit](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/2930)

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`_.pick`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#pick) to create a new object with only a specific set of properties from your original object:

```
var objectWithNoJunk = _.pick(myObject, ['state', 'country', 'counties', 'city', 'zip']);
```

Answer (score 2):

### UPDATE

@aspillers answer is the same as mine but waaay shorter/better. Go with that.

```
var listOfGoodProps = [
  "city",
  "county",
  ...
];

Object.keys(yourObj).reduce(function(acc, key) {
  if (listOfGoodProps.indexOf(key) !== -1)
    acc[key] = yourObj[key];
  return acc;
}, {});
```

No lodash needed, straight up ES 5.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.keys()`, `RegExp` `/^Junk/` to check each property of object, call `delete` if match is found

```js
var obj = {
 state: 'New York',
 country: 'usa',
 counties : [['washington','DC'],'Long Island',['New','Jersey']], 
 city : 'Manhattan',
 zip: '43543545',
 JunkOne : ['3453454','45345','45345'],
 JunkTwo: '5454545',
 JunkThree: {adc:'4545',vdfd:'45345'} 
};

var keys = Object.keys(obj);
var re = /^Junk/;
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  if (re.test(keys[i])) {
   delete obj[keys[i]]
  }
}

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need some flexiblity in what to pick, lodash `_.pickBy` is really nice.
For example:

```
const result = _.pickBy(someObject, function(value, key) {
  return key.search(/Junk/) == -1
});
```

If the function returns truthy, the key/value pair is picked from the object.

Answer (score 0):

Disappointed that none of these answers solve the problem without making a new object (copy). I want something that works like `_.set()` that can delete at a *path* without causing an error when the path doesn't completely exist. Came up with this:

```
_.set(obj, 'path.to.property', null);
delete obj.path.to.property;
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to use map with following function to extract only specific keys which you need

```
function extractKeyValuesFromObject(_obj, _keys) {
let result = {};
_keys.forEach(_k => result[_k] = _obj[_k]);
return result;
```

}